# Problem with installing LMS1xx

Tags: ros, sicklms, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am new to both ROS and Ubuntu, so if I am missing anything or doing anything horribly wrong please let me know. I am trying to install the RCPRG_laser_drivers package. I have cloned the git into /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/ and then I ran rosmake -a. When I do this I get the following in the log file:
"git clone ht tp://github.com/konradb3/libLMS1xx.git build/libLMS1xx
fatal: could not create leading directories of 'build/libLMS1xx': Permission de$
make: *** [build/libLMS1xx] Error 128"
If I run rosmake /opt/ros/groovy/RCPRG_laser_drivers I get the message:
"[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/RCPRG_laser_drivers']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/lemur2/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130308-112429
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/RCPRG_laser_drivers'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/RCPRG_laser_drivers']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names."

I would appreciate any help with this. As I have mentioned, I am brand new at this so I could be missing something completely obvious and not know it.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57515/problem-with-installing-lms1xx/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-03-08**:
I suggest running through the ROS tutorials. They'll help you understand how to create/build packages. In this case, you are attempting to build in a system directory, which is not recommended (moreover, by default, not permitted)

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-03-09**:
I've read over the tutorials, at least the early ones. I've moved the folder out of the system directory and into my home folder. Still getting the second part with the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it installed. It was because I was messing up. I didn't edit the .bashrc right so my workspace wasn't on the ros package path. Once I fixed that the package installed correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you call rosmake you don't use the full path, you need to use the package name.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-03-12**:
I tried calling the whole path since if I just called the package name it failed. Then again, it failed anyway.